# Different alignment for elements of two groupBox in a form

Tags: forms, desktop-application, alignment

I'm trying to design a settings `form` for a `Desktop Application`. There is two `groupBoxes` in the form. Each `groupBox` may contains some elements(`TextBox`, `ComboBox` , ...). Is it force for good design to align this elements with single alignment ? Or if i don't do that may it break up the rules?
Here is the screenshot with alignment:

[image]

Comment: There are common patterns, and a general rule, they say that you should align elements, but if you want a better answer, you should provide a screenshot or mockup of the design you are working on.

Comment: I second that. You can read more about form alignment here: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1502, however, regarding encapsulating some form fields it may depend on some specific case regarding your project. In general I would say it's better to have the same alignment, but sometimes it may lead to non-optimal results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be mindful of gestalt principals when grouping or aligning controls.

[Gestalt principal of perception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) states that when looking at a complex visual image, our minds see coherent, whole forms, rather than individually perceiving all of the smaller elements in the image.

For grouping controls, alignment will of course make a form more pleasing to the eye, but take care that you get the spacing right or the user will see "groups" of controls that you did not intend.

[image]

The above image illustrates what I mean in relation to your question. In the first example the alignment combined with inadequate spacing forces the user to see the controls from 2 different groups as being a single entity. In the second example all the controls are still aligned, but now the spacing aids the user in seeing them as 2 seperate groups.